# Mobile responsive dropdown not moving content properly?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I used bootstrap header,when it collapse changed to dropdown it moves the below content down, the image moves properly but the text on the image not moving down properly

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

Image moves down on dropdown but the text remains constant,i need to overlay or move the content down

my html code is:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid" id="container">
    <div class="navbar-header" >
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar" style="background: black !important;"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar" style="background: black !important;"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar" style="background: black !important;"></span>                        
      </button>
      <img src="./assets/logo.png" class="logo" >
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#" class="head-link">About</a></li>        
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle head-link" data-toggle="dropdown"  href="#">Academic <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="head-link" href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a class="head-link" href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a class="head-link" href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a class="head-link" href="#">Locations</a></li>
        <li><a class="head-link" href="#">Solutions</a></li>
        <li><a class="head-link" href="#">Resources</a></li>
        <button class="sigin-btn">Signup</button>
      </ul>      
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
    <img src="./assets/Banner.jpg"  class="banner">
    <span class="cont-line1">Out of focus-</span>
    <span class="cont-line2">Achieve with us</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I suggest you show the relevant CSS code also.

Comment: Its bootstrap no css added

Comment: We ned the CSS for .cont-line1 and 2 since that's most likely where the problem is.

Comment: .cont-line1{
  position: absolute;
  top: 375px !important;
  left: 5%;
  font-family: ITCDemi;
  font-size: 55px;
  color: #293042;
}
.cont-line2{
  position: absolute;
  top: 500px !important;
  left: 5%;
  font-family: ITCBold;
  font-size: 55px;
  color: #293042;
}

Answer (score 0):

Put this custom css on you `.dropdown-item`
If u already have some properties , You can manage it

```
.dropdown-item {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding:0;
    clear: both;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #212529;
    text-align: inherit;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
}
```

And Add this css on your css file

```
.navbar-collapse {
    max-height: calc(100vh - 60px);
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Then it will be fine ... 
Hope this works for you